# Image URI is not updated after "sharing" the first time

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I apologize in advance if I am not using the correct terminology because I am relatively new to programming with Android. I am creating an app that will edit photos and I want to allow other apps such as Photos to "share" the image with my app.

That works for the first time but if I do not close my app, switch back to the other apps such as "Photos" and share a different image. The image URI does not get updated.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/main_activity_short_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

The function I use to get image URI in OnResume() in the class that extends AppCompatActivity.

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Please let me know if you want me to provide more information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are struggling with something similar, my solution is to add

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml under Activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the activity lifecycle.
Check this document it has a nice explanation about the activity lifecycle.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

One approach, will be to set this intent instead of the onResume, to be invoked at a button.
For example a share button within a method to call this intent.

How do you wanna for application to prompt the user the option to share the image? By responding this question, maybe we can find a more suitable solution for your case.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering the question. I was trying to make my app receive images when people share with other apps. I managed to find the solution in the end.